# Javascript global variable doesn't work in jQuery Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scope, jquery-ui-draggable

This must be some exception as I'm pretty sure it should work:

```
var myvar; // global variable

function draggableinit(e, ui){
    console.log(myvar); // still defined here
    jQuery('.drop-div').droppable({
        deactivate: function(event, ui){
            console.log(myvar); // why undefined?
        }
    });
}

function set(){
    var myvar = jQuery('.cont').resizable({
        start: function(event, ui) {  },
        resize: function(event, ui) {  },
        stop: function(event, ui) { // functions to manipulate size  }
    });
    return myvar;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    myvar = set();
    jQuery('.some-div').draggable({
        "start": draggableinit
    });
});
```

I'm wondering why `myvar` is undefined in that place? Shouldn't it be accessible from any place?

Documentation: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I cannot find 'deactivate' as a valid droppable event. Where did you find it?

Comment: @fredrik You'll find it here: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: So right, don't know how I could have missed it.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7jpL/

Comment: @KevinB You're right. That's weird. My original code uses draggable multiple times, with different settings but simplified version should be the example that I pasted. I'll keep on testing to find out what the cause is. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinB I now focused on what I actually transport in that variable. It contains jQuery resizable and not `123`. With resizable it doesn't work but with `123` it does (updated question).

Comment: @Paul That still works though. http://jsfiddle.net/Q7jpL/2/

Comment: @KevinB Well, I can't reproduce that on jsfiddle even if I copy the same exact code there so this SO question doesn't make sense (but I can't delete it anyway). Believe me or not but on every droppable event except deactivate this variable exists: http://gyazo.com/839e916195b55ef133f021e1fa80c2a9.png?1363290148 Nothing in between happens (except jQuery UI execution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it directly to `window` to rule out scope conflicts. That should work. Creating `var foo` outside of an intended scope doesn't automatically make it "global", just global to *that* scope block and nested scopes.

```
function draggableinit(e, ui){
    jQuery('.drop-div').droppable({
        deactivate: function(event, ui){
            console.log(window.myvar); // why undefined?
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.myvar = 123;
    jQuery('.some-div').draggable({
        "start": draggableinit
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. It looks like I'm just not familiar with how JS is executed. Out of curiosity - would it be possible to avoid `window` or is this the only solution?

Comment: It's the same thing as `var foo = 'bar'` in the global scope. The browser assigns it to `window`. I'm just suggesting you do it manually to ensure the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it global for your script - not nessecarily global for all script. Create it in `window` or `document`.